# Getting posted data from remote url

Tags: php, web-services, sms, message

I am using PHP and Apache Server and I want values to be get posted to a url.

For eg. The remote server will post instant message data to my domain which is like "http://www.example.com/getdata/" and I will get this posted data from the url and save it to the database. 
What could be the best possible solution for achieving this? Do I need to use a web service?

Comment: Removed unnecessary sentences. Changed sentence formation to make question simple to understand

Answer (score 0):

See PHP `$_GET['value_name']`, if the data is posted like this: http://yoururl.com?value_name=b